# javan installation using python script

Tags: java, python

I’m new to python scripting  and I need to install Java using python script . please suggest a method to do this.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not wrong you are looking for silent installation of Java. Here is a link that explains the same:
[Silent installation of Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml)
Next you would want to run this command using python. For this you can use subprocess in python. Below is a link explaining it:
[Using subprocess in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators)
You want to display error stream too, so use the subprocess.Popen as:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['command plus args as in above link'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
```

out contains the output of the above command and err contains the error stream.

I would suggest you to install java from command line first, and then use this command in python script.

To install mySql or even tcl, follow similar steps,
 1. Find how to install using command line
 2. Execute the same command using python
Also, there may already be existing packages to do your job, if so you can use them.

Comment: but how do i list and provide options to process install steps for example message like "Do you want to install the software yes/no"

Comment: Well, if you just want to ask before starting the process, get the input from user (ask him to type Y or N), then compare what evr he typed in if condition. If he typed Y pr y, install software else do not install. Ex: var = raw_input("Please enter something: ");